# How to cache dynamically inserted img tag images?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, dynamic, browser-cache

I want to display images dynamically (The no. of images to be displayed varies according to data in an XML file). I use a for loop to generate the structure and then use that string to insert content via innerHTML function. The problem is that the browser fetches the images again from the server since the img tags are dynamically loaded. Is there any way around this? No. of img tags will vary according to the data in the XML file which will be updated every day. Please help

EDIT
Here are the response headers
Cache-Control:public
Connection:Close
Content-Length:304171
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Mon, 14 Sep 2015 07:05:38 GMT
ETag:"1D0DB10F92A4100"
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

Comment: The browser does NOT fetch the images "again from the server".  If these images have been loaded previously from this exact URL, they will be in either the browser memory or disk cache and will be fetched from the cache, not from the original server.  You can see this yourself if you watch the network tab in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: It does fetch them. I checked in the network tab. I insert the img tags dynamically depending on the data in the XML file. This script is present at the bottom of the page. The script fetches the data from XML file and then adds the img tags to a certain div and assigns them src found in XML file.

Comment: Check what cache headers the server sets on the images. (how to see it depends on the browser)

Comment: Either the URLs you are using have not been previously loaded by the browser or the server they come from has somehow told the browser to disable caching them.  You will need to fix one or the other of those two.  In the network tab, you need to make sure it is an over-the-network request, not fulfilled by the cache.

Comment: I am using relative path for the img src. They are not changing. The data from XML file is currently static.

Under response header for the image, cache-control is set public
Under request header for the image, Cache-Control:max-age=0

Comment: @krzy32 If the server send a `Cache-Control:max-age=0`, that means that the server don't want the browser to cache it (or with other words: cache this for 0 seconds = no cache). Please update your question with the response headers for one of your images (you can cut and paste that from the chrome browser)

Comment: I've updated my question as per your request.